# Systemwide vim mode for OSX

Tags: macos, vim

Is there a systemwide vim mode for OSX? If you are familiar with IdeaVim plugin for JetBrains you can relate to how I feel.

Such a system wide vim mode will should make all the text box cursor movement to vim style be it browser, word document, excel sheet etc

Comment: Linking to [Vim based OSX navigation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346941/vim-like-navigation-keys-for-finder/415173#415173)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some new open source alternatives cropping up every now and then, just wanted to add them here:

- [GitHub - VimMode.spoon](https://github.com/dbalatero/VimMode.spoon) - Vim emulation in all text fields
- [GitHub - SketchyVim](https://github.com/FelixKratz/SketchyVim) - Real Vim in accessible text fields

Comment: transparency: i'm the creator of this app that brings Vim Mode on macOS: https://kindavim.app
this is a paid app but the source is open, so people can remove the licensing system if they want and compile it themselves.

Answer (score 10):

No and yes!
macOS dosen't provide such kind of facility.

### But,

you can use **Karabiner**'s `Vim's ubiquitous mode`, it enables you to do vim mode editing in **every textbox**, no matter it's in a browser address bar or a stackexchange.com editor like I am typing now. and **you can even use `hjkl` to replace UpDownLeftRight arrow** when you are not in a textbox.

### To install

**Karabiner** is a free software, you can simply install it by homebrew:

```
brew cask install karabiner
```

then, enable the `Ubiquitous Vim Binding`, you can choose the normal mode trigger as you like, and as for me I choose `Ctrl-[ toggles Normal Mode`.  In addition, you can also setup system-wide Emacs Ctrl-PNBF.

If you have more questions, please leave a comment.  Happy Vimming!

Comment: `brew cask install karabiner-elements`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer here is a bit out of date (as of macOS 10.12 Sierra). As you can see from the notes in the [Karabiner repository](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md), the newer versions of macOS require `Karabiner-elements` instead and does not provide a "Ubiquitous Vim Binding" out of the box.

However, it does support "[Complex Modifications](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/)" which can be leveraged to provide Vim style keybindings using combination keystrokes. This [article](https://medium.com/@caulfieldOwen/turn-your-keyboard-into-a-text-editing-rocket-1514d8474d2d) provides detailed instructions on how to setup Karabiner-elements with complex modifications to achieve Vim bindings in many different contexts. Of course, there are many additional resources available on the web as well.

Happy `Vim`-ing!

Answer (score 1):

https://kindavim.app

i'm the creator. it brings Vim Mode in text fields through the macOS Accessibility APIs (text manipulation), and Vim Mode in UI elements through key remapping. it's a paid app (there's trial), but the source is also open. so anyone who wants to can download the source, remove the licensing and compile it themselves.

Comment: can I please get a source code?

Comment: need it for that. 
1. rename pdf books automatically: year.isbn.name.authors
2. automatically fetch pdf papers
3. full text search in books and papers with http api
4. android and or ios app that allows to search and select the book/paper 
5. ability to share a page with personal highlights as qr code:

Comment: (x.) quran recitation mode 
(xi.) apple watch app that shows quran ayat by ayat and highlights word by word when audible reciter recites it in headphones 
(xii.) instagram connection
(xv.) MacOS screen reader
(xvi.) OCR with named entity recognition on screen change
(xvii.) OCR with book name/paper references detection

Comment: (xx.) ViM mode for all accessible MacOS text fields
(xxxv.) demonstration of science books ayat by ayat with related to ayat illustration/other language translation 
(li.) splitting animes, tv shows and educational shows to animated illustration and ayats
(lv.) splitting martial arts video to the sequences
(lx.) on screen DVR for MacOS that adds content played on it: books, audiobooks, anime, tv shows, educational shows, martial arts videos to the personal library - for demonstration (phrase by phrase with voice and related illustration, on phone/apple watch/oculus quest 3), and sharing.

Comment: (lxv). automatic dual language representation of recorded material
(lxvi.) arabic-ukrainian
(lxvii.) english-ukranian
(lxviii.) arabic-english
(lxviiii.) english-arabic
(lxx.) arabic-chechen
(lxxi.) english-chechen
(lxxii.) chechen-english
(lxxiii.) chechen-ukranian
(lxxv.) avar-chechen
(lxxvi.) english-avar
(lxxvii.) avar-english
(lxxviii.) avar-ukranian
(lxxx.) arabic-tatar
(lxxxi.) english-tatar
(lxxxii.) tatar-russian
(lxxxiii.) tatar-english
(lxxxiiii.) russian-tatar

Comment: I cannot find the source code anywhere. Not on the website, not on your GitHub profile, etc. It's not really open source...

Comment: @HuonImberger even though i had made it clear i wouldn't do any OSS support, i kept receiving tons of requests. when i pointed out to the README that i wasn't doing OSS support and people could buy a license, 95% of the people said they were aware already, they just didn't want to pay. when i then pointed out other solutions, again most people said they preferred kV. the whole thing was a waste of time and energy, so i closed the source, and now i ignore those messages.